# What are the best options available for a rich UI in an ASP.NET MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

So far I've found the following components for building ASP.NET MVC views:

- [Yahoo UI (YUI)](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/)
- [Ext JS](http://extjs.com/products/extjs/)
- [Flexgrid](http://www.webplicity.net/flexigrid/) (grid only)

What are the other options that are currently available which inlcude a nice grid component?

Answer (score 2):

Check out [JQGrid](http://bartreyserhove.blogspot.com/2008/08/aspnet-mvc-and-jqgrid.html)

Answer (score 1):

[MVCContrib](http://www.codeplex.com/MVCContrib) provides a grid helper for ASP.NET MVC applications. You can read the documentation from [here](http://www.codeplex.com/MVCContrib/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Grid&referringTitle=Documentation)

Answer (score 0):

- [JQuery](http://www.urautoloads.com/ci/index.aspx)
- [JQuery Pugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/)

There are some grid plugins, which I have not used:

- [FlexGrid](http://www.webplicity.net/flexigrid/)
- [JQuery Grid plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/jquery-grid-plugin/)
- [Another JQuery Grid plugin](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?p=23)

Comment: The JQuery link goes to some automobile shipping company.